# How do I run a function which is defined in a seperate .py file in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have a function file from which I load my function. It is as follows:

```
def testFunc(A):
    B = get_rate('USD', 'JPY', datetime(2020,7,8).date()) * A
    return B
```

I also have a master file (in the same folder) from which I run everything.

```
from forex_python.converter import get_rate #necessary package

%run '/Users/mak/Dropbox/Python/Templates/getfx.py' #load function

testFunc(2) #run command
```

However, I get an error message as follows:

```
NameError: name 'get_rate' is not defined
```

If I run all the code in a single file, then it works:

```
from forex_python.converter import get_rate

def testFunc(A):
        B = get_rate('USD', 'JPY', datetime(2020,7,8).date()) * A
        return B

testFunc(2)
```

How do I solve my problem?

Note: The above is a simplification of my daily work flow. In reality I am dealing with much bigger files, which is why I can't simply put all the code in one file and run it.

Comment: can't you normally import it ?

Comment: You should `from forex_python.converter import get_rate` in the file where `get_rate` is used, not in "master file".

Comment: I usually load all my packages by running a single file because I have a lot of packages to import. Also the function is really long. Is there a way to do this separately?

Comment: you could create some keyboad shortcut with tools like [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) (Windows) or [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey) (Linux, created with Python) to paste code - and then you can paste it fast and easy in any editor which you use.

Comment: BTW: you could also try to import file which you normally run. But it may need to add folder with this file to sys.path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem, import `get_rate` inside the file with the function.

Comment: @baskesh Actually, it might be best to import the modules in the files.